# Opening Notepad and saving using python

Tags: python, notepad

I am doing automation task in which I have to open notepad, write some contents and save that file. I know how to open and do keyboard simulation. Is there any way through which I can save that opened Notepad file through script

Comment: Do you have to open notepad, could you not just write to the file?

Comment: You probably need file operations - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Are you familiar with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use the subprocess library to open notepad (assuming the person entering data knows to save the file once they are done).  #this is a bug report waiting to happen

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen(['notepad', "myfile.txt"]) #or something to this effect.
```

If what you want to do is write to a file look at the open() function you won't need notepad.

Lastly if what you want to do is fill out a form have a look at the flask, and webbrowser libraries.  (that's more complex but one of the most cross platform way to have a gui text input)

Answer (score 0):

You want [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), it provides a very easy interface to open notepad up and do operations in Notepad.

But if you just want to modify the file, then the normal python io operations would be better.

Answer (score 0):

First check how to open notepad through command then use this command in subprocess or os.system.
or use open() in os module which allow to open file.